# Call by name in scala

Tags: scala

Are both greet method same

```
object test {
  def greet = { println("hi")}                    //> greet: => Unit
  def greet1(f: => Unit)= {println("hi")}         //> greet1: (f: => Unit)Unit
}
```

As per my understand **greet** is a function which does not take any argument and return Unit and arguments are call by name. And **greet1** is a function which takes function which returns Unit and is also a call by name for its parameters.
Am confused, could anyone be kind enough to explain the difference.

Answer (score 5):

greet is a a method that returns unit.
In this particular case they do functionally the same thing. greet1 takes a function returning Unit as a parameter but does not use it. so you could call greet1 as:

```
greet1(greet)
```

And as greet is passed by parameter it would not be applied. But generally they are not the same thing. If you changed greet1 to the following:

```
def greet1(f: => Unit)= {
  println("hi")
  f()
}
```

calling greet1 as above would print "hi" twice. Or

```
def greet1(f: => Unit)= {
  println("hi")
  f()
  f()
}
```

Would print "hi" three times. As the parameter is evaluated every time the parameter is called. If you were to rewrite greet1 as:

```
def greet1(f: Unit)= {
  println("hi")
  f
  f
} // and call it:

greet1(greet)
```

It would only print "hi" twice as the parameter is call by value it is evaluated once and only once when called.